# Spring JPA update "expecting SELECT query"

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Here's the query in my repository interface:

```
@Modifying
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)
@Query("UPDATE TradeTransaction tt set tt.externalStatus = :status where tt.id = :id")
int updateTransactionExternalStatus(@Param("status") TradeTransaction.ExternalStatus status,
                                    @Param("id") Long id);
```

And here's the error:

```
org.hibernate.query.IllegalSelectQueryException: Expecting a SELECT Query [org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmSelectStatement], but found org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.update.SqmUpdateStatement [UPDATE TradeTransaction tt set tt.externalStatus = :status where tt.id = :id]
```

Everything I'm reading says the @Modifying annotation should do it.

EDIT: I've determined I don't need this kind of transaction control after all. TomekK's answer may be helpful to someone so I'll leave this up.

Comment: Maybe wrong `@Modifying` annotation (check the package)?

Comment: one Question: WHICH Library du you import for the @Query annotation? Are your shure that you import the right one?

Answer (score 2):

Locking with the use of `@Lock` doesn't work with non select `@Query`.
It looks like a bigger theme since we have this in the Query interface documentation:

> Throws: IllegalStateException - if the query is found not to be a Java
> Persistence query language SELECT query or a Criteria API query

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setLockMode(javax.persistence.LockModeType)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to import the correct @Modifying annotation. Use the one from jpa and not jdbc.

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;